# Getting Pointer of Widget made in QtDesigner

Tags: c++, qt

I'm pretty to new using Qt and C++ so; please bear with me.

Right now I am designing a UI using the QtDesigner and want to change the minimum value of a slider based on the current value of another slider.

I figured that I would need to find the pointer to the slider I want to change but I'm not sure how I would do that.

I'm wondering if this was possible or if I'm going to need to create the UI in code instead.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ui->yourUiItem
```

contains the pointer to your UI element unless you named the UI object differently.

I'm talking about: `Ui::YourClass *ui;` for example.

---

You can access it the same way as you would an object created manually.

For example `ui->yourUiItem->text( )`

Comment: Thanks I figured it out! My UI object didn't come with as a pointer though so I just did something along the lines of this: `Ui::QtCvClass *uiPtr = &ui`

Comment: I take it you're missing `ui( new Ui::QtCvClass )` and `ui->setupUi( this )` from your constructor and `delete ui` from your destructor?

Comment: My constructor has what you are talking about, but I am missing `delete ui` from my destructor. Is this necessary?

Comment: @EndingLegacy If you have a member variable `ui` already, you don't need to convert it to a pointer. Just use the `ui` variable you have.